# Redirecionar página após o envio do arquivo para download

Tags: php

Tenho uma página que ao ser carregada manda um arquivo pdf para download. Como faço para depois que o arquivo ser enviados ao browser, redirecionar a página?

Estou enviando o arquivo assim fazer assim:

```
// Dados do arquivo
$file = "Arquivos/documento.pdf";

// Configuramos os headers que serão enviados para o browser
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));

// Limpa o conteúdo interno do buffer
ob_clean();
flush();

// Envia o arquivo para o cliente
readfile($file);

// Descarrega o conteúdo interno do buffer
ob_end_flush();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não sei bem o contexto, mas talvez se você fizer essa página que força o download abrir em um target="_blank" já resolva o download. Pra redirecionar daria pra tratar o click com JS, assim:

`<a href="baixa_pdf.php" target="_blank" download onclick="javascript:location.href='redir.php'">Baixar</a>`